# Unable to Inject ServletContext in application scoped CDI bean

Tags: cdi

I'm trying to inject ServletContext in application Scooped bean.

```
@Named("propertyProducer")
@ApplicationScoped
public class PropertyProducer {
    private Properties properties;
    @Inject
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    private String fileName = "app.properties";
```

Its giving following exception-

```
#|2017-07-05T14:24:46.424+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=76;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app : WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [ServletContext] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject com.advisory.compass.webapps.blocks.security.PropertyProducer.servletContext]
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [ServletContext] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject com.advisory.compass.webapps.blocks.security.PropertyProducer.servletContext]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:311)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:280)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:163)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:382)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:367)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:380)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

You inject ServletContext from package `com.advisory.compass.webapps.blocks.security.PropertyProducer.servletContext`

That is wrong. You should import `javax.servlet.ServletContext`.

```
package somePackage;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;


@ApplicationScoped
public class Appbean {

@Inject
private ServletContext servletContext;

public String greet() {
    return "Hello";
}

}
```